# Why are there no tutorials for Django using Windows?

Tags: windows, django

I'm starting to use Django and I find that every example I see is done in Mac OS. I'm a Windows user. I've used Mac OS X Lion and I have no problem with it other that my personal computer doesn't have it. I would prefer not to go out and spend money on an operating system and set up dual booting just to follow a quick tutorial for Django.
So my question Is, can anyone point me in to a tutorial that uses Windows so I can get a good idea of how it works, and get a good ground, so that I can translate the other tutorials a little more easily.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what parts of learning django are not platform agnostic beyond the way filesystem paths look?

Answer (score 1):

There are no windows specific django tutorials because django as a framework is platform agnostic. All of the python code that goes into writing a project is the same across platforms. The only time you would see something different is when a tutorial references a path on the filesystem.

The actual installation process of django would however be platform specific, but thats more of just a python for windows question. It would be the same situation for installing any python package or framework.

Ultimately you only have a few commands you need to actually run when you are learning django:

```
python manage.py syncb
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py shell
```

How you call python is the platform specific part, but the django aspect is the same. The project file structure is also the same. As long as a project doesn't use platform specific file path references, you could run a project written under linux on windows.

This doc might be the only one you need, which explains various installation procedures:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/

If you need more info, you might need to provide some specific examples of where its confusing you to see non-windows style tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly old tutorial: http://mirkobonadei.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/install-python-and-django-on-windows/

The official Django docs also have a section on installation, which covers Windows: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/

Comment: no no I have it installed, I mean like making a simple form or something. I have a hard time following along because the terminal commands are different from command prompt and you sometimes have to take a few extra steps. I do appreciate the quick reply though. Thank you.